# What does fibaux(n)[0] mean in python?

Tags: java, python, function

So i am looking at a code that is a more efficient fibonacci calculator, but i do not understand what return fibaux(n)[0] means. I am trying to convert it to java and I almost have it, but i do not understand this part. Thank you!

```
 def fib(n):
 ## Handle special case when n == 0
 if n == 0:
    return 0
## General case, return the first of the
## two values returned by fibaux
else:
    return fibaux(n)[0]

## Auxiliary function
## Return the nth and (n-1)th Fibonacci numbers
## n must be an integer >= 1
def fibaux(n):
  ## Base case of for recursion
  if n == 1:
     return 1, 0
  else:
    ## Recursive case
    f2, f1 = fibaux(n - 1)
    return f2 + f1, f2
```

Ok thanks guys! I understand that now, but i guess i was not on the right track in converting this to java because I am not getting the correct outputs, this is what i wrote:

```
  public class Fibonacci {

   public static int[] fib(int number){
      if (number == 0){
       return new int[] {0};
     }
     else{
       int fibauxArray[] = fibaux(number);
       int f3 = fibauxArray[0];
       return new int[] {f3};
     }
    }

public static int[] fibaux(int number){
  if (number == 1){
     return new int[] {1, 0};
  }
  else{
     int[] Q = fibaux(number-1);
     int f2 = Q[0]+Q[0];
     int f1 = Q[0];
     return new int[] {f2, f1};
 }

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: It returns the first element of the tuple returned by `fibaux` function.

Answer (score 1):

`fibaux` returns a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (an unchangeable list) of two numbers:

```
>>> fibaux(3)
(2, 1)
```

`[0]` takes the item at index 0 (the first number):

```
>>> fibaux(3)[0]
2
```

I believe if you are porting this to Java, you'll either want to use `fibaux(n).get(0)` (if `fibaux` returns a `List`) or `fibaux(n)[0]` (if `fibaux` returns an `Array`)